# findbugs plugin installation in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, plugins

I'm using debian 9, netbeans 8.1.
I click Source->inspect now install and I get:

`"Findbugs integration" module has not been downloaded.`

I googled and there is no updated findbugs for netbeans 8.1.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue in NetBeans 8.0 (see [NetBeans bug 243024](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243024)), but it should have been fixed for 8.1. (I have also verified that the FindBugs plugin works fine with release 8.2.)

First verify that the plugin is installed and active:

- **Tools > Plugins >** select the **Installed** tab and sort by **Name**.
- Scroll down and verify that the **Findbugs Integration** plugin is installed and **Active**.
- If not then select the **Available Plugins** tab, locate the **Findbugs Integration** plugin and click **Install**.

Once the plugin is installed and active it should work immediately (no need to restart NetBeans) when you select **Source > Inspect** with **Configuration** set to **FindBugs**, with FindBugs messages logged in the **Inspector** tab.

If you still have problems:

- Open the error log: **View > IDE Log**
- Update your post with the content of that log around the time of failure.